# About Asian ancestor worship, do we say "he is praying for his grandpa" or "he is worshipping his grandpa"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Ancestor worship is very popular in Asia. Asian people take great care in preserving the memories of their ancestors and honoring them with regular prayers and offerings. Ancestor worship is such an integral part of Asian culture that many would not even recognize it as a religion; it's just a part of life.

Ok, that is the background.

For example, look at this picture. First the person will touch his 2 palms together like in the picture & look at the altar.

> [image: screenshot]

Then he will slowly bow down like in this picture.

> [image: screenshot]

He, then, may repeat that movement two or more times to pray or worship.

Sometimes, he may do the same but with some burned sticks of incense between their two palms like in this picture.

> [image: screenshot]

> **[worship](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/worship_2)** [transitive] worship somebody/something to show respect for God or a god, especially by saying prayers, singing, etc.
> with other people in a religious building
>
> The Mayans built jungle pyramids to worship their gods.

> **[pray](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pray_1?q=pray)** [intransitive, transitive] to speak to God, especially to give thanks or ask for help
>
> They knelt down and prayed.
>
> pray for somebody/something I'll pray for you.
>
> to pray for peace
>
> pray to somebody (for somebody/something) She prayed to God for an end
> to her sufferings.
>
> pray (that)… We prayed (that) she would recover from her illness.
>
> pray to do something He prayed to be forgiven.
>
> - speech ‘Please God don't let it happen,’ she prayed.

Do we say *he is praying for his grandpa* or *he is worshiping his grandpa*?

Comment: In my culture the difference between *pray to* and *pray for* has more to do with the thoughts/words associated with the prayer than with the motions and gestures associated with the prayer (as indicated in Astralbee's answer below).  It would be helpful to know what thoughts/words are in mind of the person praying.  If there are no thoughts but only motions, I am not sure that would count as praying but instead worshipping.  I think there is a distinction between worshipping and praying that may not be understood by Westerners in this situation.

Comment: I wouldn’t necessarily say they are praying at all, but rather **paying** respect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is partly a theological question rather than purely a language question. I'm going to assume you understand the theology aspect and know what you are trying to express in language.

In English, there is a distinction between "pray *for*" and "pray *to*".

Prayers are directed *to* a god or deity, and what you pray *for* is the *subject matter* of your prayer - what you are asking your god to do. For example:

> I prayed to God for my brother to get well.

So, in the case of "ancestor worship", I imagine it would depend on whether the theology teaches that your prayer is *heard* by the ancestor, or whether you are praying to someone else *on behalf of* the ancestor.

---

On the matter of "worship" - this is defined as "the feeling or expression of reverence and adoration for a deity". In most religions, prayer is considered "an act of worship" - but again, it is an act of worship to the person or deity the prayer is *addressed to*, not for the *subject*.